# Connect shapefile from postgres in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Why do not show the shapefile imported in postgres to qgis conection? how its possible to make a new database and import new shapefile ? How to set SRID projection to a shapefile ?

I try to import a shapefile and do not allow me to put SRID 31700.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Code 31700 in not known by PostGIS nor the current version of EPSG database. This page suggests that the projection is deprecated https://epsg.io/31700

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the included DB Manager from QGIS to load the data in PostgreSQL.
From QGIS open Database/DB Manager and connect to your localhosted PostGIS database.
In the DB Manager window just use the upload/load button to add the data to the databse:
[image]

Also the SRID 31700 is deprecated (it is the old Romanian reference system) that has been updated to EPSG:3844 since 2005-2006. While the coordinates in the projections stay the same, reprojections to other coordinate systems (ex. WGS84 is greatly, greatly increased).